# How to Correctly mock an object with Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am trying to test the ClientDetails class below and trying to learn JUnit and Mockito at the same time.

```
// this is the class I'm trying to test
public class ClientDetails {

    @Autowired private IApplicantService<Applicant> applicantService;
    @Autowired private ClientDetailsHelpers helpers;

    public FullClientDetails getClientDetails(String businessId, boolean isNewClient) {

        FullClientDetails fcd = new FullClientDetails(); 

        ClientParams params = new ClientParams();
        params.setBusinessId(businessId);

        ApplicantId ai = applicantService.retrieveApplicantIdFromBusinessId(params);
        Long applicantId = ai.getApplicantId();
        params.setApplicantId(applicantId);

        Applicant applicant = applicantService.retrieveApplicantDetailsByHerdNumber(params);
        helpers.validateRetrievedApplicant(applicant, isNewClient, businessId);

        fcd.setApplicant(applicant);
        // more method calls that get and assign objects to the fcd object

        return fcd;
    }


}
```

---

```
// ClientDetailsHelpers.java method that throws exception
public void validateRetrievedApplicant(Applicant applicant, boolean isNewClient, String businessId) {
    if (applicant.getApplicantId() == null && !isNewClient) {
        throw new ValidationSearchException(businessId);
    }
}
```

---

```
// test class
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ClientDetailsTest {

    private final static String BUSINESS_ID = "A1234567";
    private final static Long APPLICANT_ID = null;

    @InjectMocks
    ClientDetails clientDetails;

    @Mock ApplicantServiceImpl applicantService;
    @Mock ClientDetailsHelpers helpers;

    private ApplicantParams params;
    private Applicant applicantWithInvalidId = new Applicant();

    ApplicantId applicantId = new ApplicantId(APPLICANT_ID, BUSINESS_ID);

    @Before
    public void before(){
        applicantWithInvalidId.setApplicantId(null);
    }

    @Test(expected = ValidationSearchException.class)
    public void testGetFullApplicationDetails(){
        when(applicantService.retrieveApplicantIdFromBusinessId(Mockito.any(ApplicantParams.class))).thenReturn(applicantId);
        when(applicantService.retrieveApplicantDetailsByHerdNumber(Mockito.any(ApplicantParams.class))).thenReturn(applicantWithInvalidId);
        FullClientDetails fcd = clientDetails.getFullClientDetails(BUSINESS_ID , false);
    }
}
```

In my test class I create some mock objects, including an **ApplicantId** object to be returned when **applicantService**.*retrieveApplicantIdFromBusinessId()* is called and **Applicant** object with is applicantId attribute set to null  to be return when **applicantService**.*retrieveApplicantDetailsByHerdNumber()* is called.

The function **ClientDetailsHelper**.*validateRetrievedApplicant()* should throw an exception if **Applicant**.*getApplicantId()* returns a null and if the boolean *isNewClient* is set to false however it doesn't seem to be happening in the test, it throws no exception and the @Test fails.

My best guess is that I am not using *when().thenReturn()* to correctly return the Applicant and ApplicantId objects I have created and instead another Applicant object is getting passed to validateRetrievedApplicant() and returning and applicantId of 0 when it gets to the validation method.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Not only JUnit and Mockito. Together with Spring. Imho: that sounds a little bit like overburdening yourself. In other words: don't do three complicated things at once. When Mockito is new to you, then work basic Mockito tutorials. And then, when you got *some* experience, go forward and apply that to your production code. Or do you think it would be wise to learn "unicycle riding" and "juggling" *at the same time*?

Comment: Thanks @GhostCat. Well, I've been given this code base to maintain/develop and it has no unit tests. I don't really know how to unit test so I thought I'd use the real-world scenario to learn.

Comment: I am sure that some people are able to learn juggling whilst riding the unicycle. But for the rest of us: go slow. In order to be efficient with "trial and error" - you need some experience in that field. Otherwise you all your "trials" will go "error".

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not throwing an exception because there is nowhere in the code you are testing that throws that exception. I assume your exception is thrown within the ClientDetailsHelpers class but you are mocking this class so it will not call the actual code and so no exception will be thrown.

You need to think about what you want to test. Do you want to test the ClientDetails class in isolation as a unit? In which case you don't need to worry about the exception being thrown since its not part of the functionality of that class.

The second option is that you want to do more of an integration test where you pull in an actual ClientDetailsHelpers class but in order to do this you will need to include some configuration in your test to make sure that this bean is available to the test Spring context. You can do this using a Spring4JunitRunner instead of the Mockito one and then pulling in a configuration class with a component scan for your ClientDetailsHelpers class using the @ContextConfiguration(MyConfig.class) annotation on your test class where MyConfig is the relevant Spring config class.